# Dimension of polynomial rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

It is well known that if $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then $\dim A[T]=\dim A+1$ and $\dim A[[T]]=\dim A+1$. Now $1$ is the fibre dimension of the faithfully flat algebras $A\rightarrow A[T]$ (resp. $A[[T]]$?). Are there more general formulas for (flat) algebras $A\rightarrow B$ connecting $\dim A$, $\dim B$ and the fibre dimension? Also how is flatness related to fibre dimension?

Comment: Do you know scheme language?

Comment: A local version is the following: $(A,m) \to (B,n)$ is a local homomorphism, then $\dim B \le \dim A + \dim (B/mB)$ with equality if the morphism is flat.  The fiber is $B/mB$. I'm pretty sure that a standard commutative algebra text books such as ones by Matsumura and Eisenbud have a through treatment of the topic. All as @paf mentioned you can find in a geometric setup for instance in Hartshorne's book on algebraic geometry. But as usual  you can also google a topic like dimension of fibers and flatness.

Comment: Yes, and there is also a converse statement: if $(A,\mathfrak m)$ is regular and $(B,\mathfrak n)$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then flatness is *equivalent* to the equality $\dim B=\dim A+\dim B/\mathfrak mB$.

Comment: @Youngsu, paf:  I know the local versions and miracle flatness, but I don't know a global one. Yeah I do know scheme language paf, but I want a statement in the affine case